# how to make a universal request with different attributes of categories (heroes, planets, spaceships) https://swapi.co/api

Tags: javascript, ajax

How to make 3 categories in a query with different attributes, but with the same number of attributes (only one name is the same). This is an example of the first category of heroes, there are planets and starships, the code is the same, only the names of variables change and the attributes change. I want to optimize the code

```js
     var url = "https://swapi.co/api/people";
                
          function heroes() {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        /////////////////////////request to swapi///////////////
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                            console.log(data); /////// check object 
       //////////////create table////////////////////////////////////////
                        var tableContent = '<table>'
                        tableContent += "<thead><tr>";
                        tableContent += "<td>Name</td>";
                        tableContent += "<td>Height</td>";
                        tableContent += "<td>Mass</td>";
                        tableContent += "<td>Eye Color</td>";
                        tableContent += "<td>Skin Color</td>";
                        tableContent += "<td>Gender</td>";
                        tableContent += "</tr></thead>";
        //////////////////////////////select atributes and build table/////////////
        
                        for(var i=0;i<data.results.length;i++) {
                            var person = data.results[i];
        
                            tableContent += "<tr>";
                            tableContent += "<td>" + person.name + "</td>";
                            tableContent += "<td>" + person.height + "</td>";
                            tableContent += "<td>" + person.mass + "</td>";
                            tableContent += "<td>" + person.eye_color + "</td>";
                            tableContent += "<td>" + person.skin_color + "</td>";
                            tableContent += "<td>" + person.gender + "</td>";
                            tableContent += "</tr>";
                        }
        
                        tableContent += "</table>";
                /////////show info on click/////////////////////////////////////
        document.getElementById("hero").addEventListener("click",function () {
//////////////////////// show table without info////////////////// 
                            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = tableContent;  
////////////// hide loader///////////////
                            document.getElementById("load").style.display = "none";
                        });
        
                    }
        
                };
                xhr.open("get", url, true);
                xhr.send();
            }
        
            heroes();
```

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Is this problem/issue still relevant? If yes, **I'm interested to solve it**, but can you give me a more detailed description on what is the expected result? Can you give me a link to a similar website, a form, a video, a screenshot, etc. to be **more clear* what you exactly need before I solve the issue? Thanks!